# Upload quickly project to Launchpad with "quickly share" not working!

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly, launchpad, application-submission

I want to upload my quickly project for the Ubuntu App Showdown.
I signed the Ubuntu Code of Conduct successfully and created a project "interest-calculation" on my Launchpad-Portal.

When I enter in my project-folder the following command:

`quickly share`

I get the following error-output:

```
Lade Launchpad-Einstellungen
Erfolgreich mit Launchpad verbunden
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 127, in <module>
 print(_("%s does not exist. Please create it on launchpad if you want to push a  package to it. %s has the following ppas available:") % (e, ppa_user.name))
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
FEHLER: Befehl share fehlgeschlagen
Wird abgebrochen
```

What should I do? I am ready with coding but without uploading the project to Launchpad I can't participate the Ubuntu App Showdown.

I also tried:

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

After that I will be asked for the project (witch has the same name on Launchpad as on my filesystem "interest-calculation".

```
Lade Launchpad-Einstellungen
Erfolgreich mit Launchpad verbunden
No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.
Launchpad project name: interest-calculation
Kein Projekt gefunden, leave blank to abort, 0 for another search.
```

I also created a "dput.cf" on my home-dir with the following input:

```
[ppa]
fqdn = ppa.launchpad.net
method = ftp
incoming = ~reg-mlux/ppa/ubuntu
login = anonymous
allow_unsigned_upload = 0
```

I found that on a video-tutorial for "Submitting your app" on the App Showdown Page.

Comment: `witch` should be `which` (so that online language translation services can work properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
quickly configure bzr lp:~launchpadUserName/launchpadProject/trunk
quickly configure ppa launchpadUserName/launchpadProject
quickly share
```

After these steps, I think you must upload the .tar.gz file created with:

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It works!!!!I uploaded the project yesterday with the following commands manually: "bzr push lp:~reg-mlux/interest-calculation/trunk"! The quickly-solution is much better!!